# How can these two definitions of the eccentric anomaly give the same answer?

Tags: astrophysics, orbital-motion, astronomy, celestial-mechanics

The [eccentric anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentric_anomaly),$E$, is defined via the equation,

$$ r = a(1-e \cos E) \tag{1} $$
for radius $r$, semi-major axis $a$ and eccentricity $e$.

It is ALSO defined in terms of the [Kepler Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation) as,

$$ E - e \sin E =  \frac{2 \pi t}{T} \tag{2} $$
for time $t$, orbital period $T$.

Now I have some data $r(t)$, where I know the orbital parameters $a,e,T$.

From my data, if I calculate $E$ from the first equation, I can calculate the LHS of Eq. 2.

I can also calculate the RHS of Eq. 2 directly from my data.

However when I do this LHS $\ne$ RHS: The RHS increases ~linearly, whilst the LHS is ~ oscillatory. Given the form of these two equations, this is what I would expect, but how can I get the two to agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E$ is monotonic like $t$. It isn’t limited to be between $0$ and $2\pi$.

Comment: So does that mean it is not possible to calculate $E$ from equation 1, given $r(t)$?

Comment: (1) determines $E$ modulo $2\pi$. It doesn’t know how many times you’ve gone around the ellipse.

Comment: What are you actually trying to *do*? If you already know $r(t)$, why would you care about the eccentric anomaly? Usually the point of using these two equations is to calculate $r(t)$, but I assume you have done that instead by numerical integration of the equations of motion.